# One good video for Resharper rampup

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, resharper, resharper-5.0

I'm installing it now.  I've seen a few videos where people have Resharper installed and it is amazing how fast they are writing code and navigating.  In the past, I've had to uninstall Resharper because it was too much adjustment and too many of my keybindings were changed.  Now I'm on a project where it is required.

The reality is, I have time for one good video on Resharper today. I'd like to come back and watch more videos but unfortunately I can only do one.  During my normal work day, I will be exploring the code base of an existing project.

Can you recommend a video to start with that might improve my productivity today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReSharper overview video: http://tv.jetbrains.net/videocontent/what-is-resharper

When you have time, watch more videos from the [ReSharper channel](http://tv.jetbrains.net/channel/resharper) on JetBrains TV or take a couple of hours to take an awesome [ReSharper course by Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents?courseName=resharperfundamentals)

Btw you didn't say what kind of project you're working on. If it's any kind of project that uses XAML, I'd recommend [Using ReSharper for developing WP7 Applications](http://tv.jetbrains.net/videocontent/resharper-wp7) as an overview of how ReSharper helps in WPF/WP7/Silverlight. Otherwise, "What is ReSharper" is the best pick.

Answer (score 1):

[Demos](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/demos/) from ReSharper itself. Pick the one that you like (selection from 14), they just highlight different areas.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Resharper, but turn off all of their silly key bindings.  That's what I've done, as I work with VS a lot at home, and don't need to make switching between home and work difficult.

I'm curious, how exactly is it "required?"  Surely they're not monitoring whether or not you're actually using it?

Comment: Silly keybindings? What do you mean?

Comment: oh you had to call my bluff, didn't you?  Ok, it is very strongly suggested.  One reason is that StyleCop (or FxCop?) is run by resharper at edit time, and we need to conform to those rules -- otherwise or else -- (breaks the build?)

Comment: Silly keybindings, as in it takes over most of the VS keybindings that I already know, and makes them do something different, or brings up a dialog to do in five clicks what was once one.

Comment: @MedicineMan:  Yup, we have that too.  Like I said, just install it and turn off the keybindings and intellisense it offers, and that will allow you to keep StyleCop and still use the features it has when you want, instead of jumping into your face.